# Android Imageview is being cropped inside gridview

Tags: java, android

I have the following layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ededed" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#172982"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Stories" />

   <GridView
       android:id="@+id/grid"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:clipChildren="true"
       android:columnWidth="150dp"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:numColumns="auto_fit"
       android:scrollbars="none"
       android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >

    </GridView>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="9dp"
        android:paddingRight="9dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

         <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#172982"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Dictionaries" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

In this layout I'm filling each cell of the gridview with a linearlayout containing an imageview and a textview through the following xml file :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true">
    </ImageView>

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/grid_text"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
       android:text="asdsadas"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       android:textSize="20sp" >

    </TextView>



</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is the imageviews inside the gridview are being cropped (cut in half), I'm not able to see the whole image. Any solution please ?

Comment: your image width might be larger than column width size. Thats why image is being cropped.

Comment: I've got the solution, the first image that was loaded was null, the gridview was taking its height and wrapping everything

Answer (score 0):

set Imageview's android:scaleType property to "centerCrop"